# Remember me plugin is not working on Joomla2.5

Tags: php, joomla2.5

anybody please help me. Actually I am using Joomla2.5. In this I have used Remember Me Plugin. But the Remember Me functionality is not working. Actually what is the requirement means If the particular user click the Remember Me check box, after log out immediately if he want to login again means the username and password should be appear automatically. Please help me anybody...

srinivas.p
joomla learner.

Answer (score 0):

In This case the Problem is session.cookie_lifetime value in my php.ini

The php.ini is not a part of the Joomla filesystem. Many hosters don´t allow to manipulate this file. But there is a workaround for this.

How i sayed you can´t change the value in the php.ini often especially by cheap hosting packages. But you can change the value local.

To do this first you need to upload a file to youre joomlaroot directory

call the file phpinfo.php

in this file you write this following line:

```
Code:

<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

this file will help you to look how youre session.cookie_lifetime value is set.

then you open youre site with

youresite.com/phpinfo.php

then a list will open. Than you look after the entry: session.cookie_lifetime

if the both values are 0 than you have youre answer why youre remember is not working.

Next step you go again in youre file phpinfo.php and add some code. After that it will look so:

```
Code:

<?php ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 536*60*60); phpinfo(); ?>
```

you have added than this part:

```
Quote:

ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 536*60*60);
```

this new part you will need in another place. You will need it in youre index.php

theire you will add this direct under this:

Code:

the 536 stays for the hours. So with 536 hours youre cookies will last 1 month. If you want more or less change it in both files or leave it so. But don´t change the other values. Its a security-risk than.

I hope it helped you. I searched long after that sollution